# Vuetify - How to keep the first expansion panel open by default and if I open another panel, the others should be close?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Basically, the thing is I have 4 expansion panel and I want the first panel should be open or expanded by default and when I click on the second panel the first one should be close.

In vuetify doc they have both the eg. one for how to by default open the panel and second is, when one should open others should be closed.

```
<template>
  <div>
 <div class="text-xs-center mb-3">{{ panel }}</div>    
 <v-expansion-panel
  expand
  v-model="panel">
  <v-expansion-panel-content
    v-for="(details,index) in marketCapDetails"
    :key="index">
    <template v-slot:header>
       <p>{{details.sr_no }}</p>
       <p>{{details.currency }}</p>
    </template>
    <v-card>
      #some code
    </v-card>      
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
</v-expansion-panel>
```

and in my script

```
export default {   
  data() {
    return {
            panel:[true, false, false, false]
         }   
      }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `v-model="panel"` which is equal arrays of indexes of expanded items

```html
<v-expansion-panels v-model="panel"
 <v-expansion-panel
  expand
  v-model="panel">
  <v-expansion-panel-content
    v-for="(details,index) in marketCapDetails"
    :key="index">
    <template v-slot:header>
       <p>{{details.sr_no }}</p>
       <p>{{details.currency }}</p>
    </template>
    <v-card>
      #some code
    </v-card>      
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
 </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

```js
data() {
 return {
   panel: [0]
 }
}
```

The `value` prop takes a number when you're not using `expand`.

From the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels):

> Corresponds to a zero-based index of the currently opened content.

Comment: yes it is, but then I cant have my first expansion open by default.

Comment: excuse me, now how it is working by setting only 0 value to the panel? no true/false? can you just explain me little bit? I also follow the doc but didnt understand. #help

Comment: It's a 0 based index, so first panel is 0, second is 1, third is 2, fourth 3 and so on.

Comment: There was a breaking change that `expand` is deprecated in favor of `multiple`.
When you want to have open first two panels (in multiple mode) you have: 
`panel: [0, 1]`

and if you want to have open the first panel in the "single-open" mode (with multiple not being set, then you set it with:
`panel: 1`

Comment: This won't work without "multiple" prop in v-expansion-panels (which is not properly closed). Delete also second v-model prop.

This did the trick for me:

```<v-expansion-panels v-model="panel"
 <v-expansion-panel
  expand
  v-model="panel">
  <v-expansion-panel-content
    v-for="(details,index) in marketCapDetails"
    :key="index">
    <template v-slot:header>
       <p>{{details.sr_no }}</p>
       <p>{{details.currency }}</p>
    </template>
    <v-card>
      #some code
    </v-card>      
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
 </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>```

Comment: This awnser helped me! But mine isn't with Multiple, so only change the Array [ ] to a simple Int 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

In the meanwhile there have been breaking changes:

If you have 4 panels and the first and the third should be open:

```
panel: [0, 2]
```

Without the multiple prop its only the index of the panel and not an array:

```
panel: 0
```

(first panel open)

Comment: Why isn't this information on the documentation!!! The amount of time I've lost figuring why the documentation example wouldn't work for a single panel (using an array of only one value) was insane. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the first item to be open by default use the 'mandatory' prop

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the `:value` attribute on the expansion panels.
This attribute can also help if you are only using one expansion panel.

Example:

```
  <v-expansion-panels :value="opened">
   <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-header>
        Incomes and Expenses monthly
      </v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
      ...
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
```

...

```
data() {
return {
  opened: 0,
}
```

},

According with : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panels/#props-value

Comment: from the question it's clear that user isn't interested in a situation with only one panel.

Comment: I specified this because v-model only works with multiple panels, while :value works with single and multiple panels.

Comment: @Calisto FYI I'm using `v-model` on a single expansion panel, and it works great

Comment: Works perfectly with multiple panels, but if you want to expand only one of them